# Can I access an API without authentication in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, web-applications

### Circumstances

I develope a WebApp with AngularJS.

- I've an restful API on server-side with `GET` and `POST` commands.
- I want to use the API within my module (means: in JavaScript) to display and edit my data.
- I want to protect the API with some kind of authentication (basic auth with an API key for example)
- **I don't want to protect the API when a user uses the app itself**

### Actual question

Okay, I guess the last point is a bit unclear.

I want that a user can use the app with his browser without any authentication
But when a third-party app want to access the API it have to use authentication

Since JavaScript is executed on client-side of course I can't write a *master* key into js or something similar..

Is there any kind of pattern or solution to solve this problem?

### More specifications

referring to [@EliranMalka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547020/elirana-malka) and [@shaunhusain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509344/shaunhusain)

On the server-side I do use [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) with it's builtin template engine. I do use the template engine actually just to [write](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write) the index page and insert CSS, JS dynamically.

The code for authentication would just something like:

```
def is_authenticated(request):
    if 'api_key' in request.arguments:
        return sql('SELECT id FROM keys WHERE key=%S' % request.arguments['api_key']).count == 1
```

My AngularJS module is doing something similar to:

```
$http.get('/api/foo?api_key=1234')
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.data = result.data
});
```

As you can see I'm writing my API key into js at the moment. But I wan't to avoid this.

> Also, what do you mean exactly by third-party?

**not a** third-party request would be: Using the App on http:/ /app.example.com with a browser

A third-party request would be from an Android app for example. Something that comes from *outside* or *remote*.
A JS request from the browser **on** the actual page would be *not* from *remote* (again: since it's JS it is actually from *remote* - but I hope it gets more clear now)

### Oh and before I forget...

I'm aware of that my plan is a bit weird - but it's just a *learning(-web-development)-by-doing* project.
Also the *API key* is not absolutely to avoid abusion, it is rather to log 3rd-party usage.

PS I hope my question was clear for you

Comment: You're being unclear. In what circumstances exactly you *don't* want to protect it? Do you perhaps mean: expose it as is for the **Java API** layer, and protect the **REST API** via HTTP authentication? Also, what do you mean **exactly** by *third-party*?

Comment: @EliranMalka updated my question - hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well I'll try to address the questions but here's a few things.

1. Question isn't really appropriate in it's current format for stackoverflow.com (should be programming questions, I tried X and Y happened) perhaps closer to a StackExchange question but is still fairly open ended.
2. Include more information about specifics of the languages (and/or frameworks) your using server side and any code you have that is relevant (authentication code?).
3. Putting the key into the client code and transmitting it from the client means anyone with a web proxy (check out Charles or Wireshark) can grab the key so just to reiterate you're right there that's not the way to go.

Check out how other organizations allow you to get access to their APIs (for example Google, LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter) to get a feel for how it works.  In all of these cases you are signed into the service to be able to make an API key, in some cases you have to specify which domain the requests with that API key will come from.  If you use the same precautions and check the API key sent with a request against a database of registered API users and verify the domain in the request then I'd say you're in pretty good shape.